# Rather Tricky Code Smell to Solve (Due to two separate libraries) c++

Tags: c++, excel, polymorphism, xls, xlsx

I have a program which Converts excel to data by reading in each cell one at a time, iterating over row-by-row.

To accomplish this, I've been using two separate libraries:

[ExcelFormat (for xls)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library)

[Xlsx I/O](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xlsxio/)

I have an abstract class for the algorithm, and two derived classes for each. The issue I'm running into, is that ExcelFormat and Xlsx I/O do not follow the same format (as they are separate libraries, and don't conform to the same base class).

(Note, I wrote a wrapper for xlsxio because it is procedural, and I wanted OO functionality)

I want to abstract the algorithm as much as possible to the base class.

As it stands, all I've really been able to do is have the common abstract method Convert(), which is very poor, because both functions are algorithmic-ally very similar, but are unable to conform to a unified interface simply because they don't share the same base.

Here's what I have:

```
bool XlsxToData::Convert(const std::string & filePath, std::list<SqlParam*>* params) {
    FreeXlsx::XlsxBook book(filePath);

    if (book.IsOpen()) {

        std::vector<std::string>* sheets = book.GetSheetList();
        if (sheets != nullptr) {
            std::list<SqlParam*> foundParams;

            for (auto itr : *sheets) {

                FreeXlsx::XlsxSheet sheet(itr, book);

                std::map<int, SqlParam*> foundX;

                int longestWidth = 0;
                int lastWidth = 0;

                if (sheet.IsOpen()) {

                    sheet.ForSheet([this, &foundParams, &foundX, &longestWidth, &lastWidth, params](const std::string & value, const int & x, const int & y) {
                        if (x > longestWidth)
                            longestWidth = x;

                        lastWidth = x;

                        GetValueCell(foundX, value, x);

                        CheckParams(foundX, foundParams, value, x, params);
                    },
                        [&longestWidth, &lastWidth, &foundX, this](const int & row) {

                        if (lastWidth < longestWidth)
                            for (int i = lastWidth + 1; i <= longestWidth; ++i) {
                                auto find = foundX.find(i);

                                if (find != foundX.end()) {

                                    find->second->PushValue("");
                                }
                            }

                    });

                    sheet.Close();
                }

                if (params->size() < 1)
                    break;
            }

            delete sheets;

            while (foundParams.size() > 0) {
                params->push_back(*foundParams.begin());
                foundParams.erase(foundParams.begin());
            }

        }

        book.Close();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool XlsToData::Convert(const std::string & filePath, std::list<SqlParam*>* params) {
    ExcelFormat::BasicExcel book;

    if (book.Load(filePath.c_str())) {
        int sheets = book.GetTotalWorkSheets();
        std::list<SqlParam*> foundParams;

        for (int i = 0; i < sheets; ++i) {
            ExcelFormat::BasicExcelWorksheet* sheet = book.GetWorksheet(i);

            std::map<int, SqlParam*> foundX;

            if (sheet != nullptr) {
                const int rows = sheet->GetTotalRows();
                const int cols = sheet->GetTotalCols();

                std::map<int, SqlParam*> foundX;

                for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
                    bool willBreak = false;

                    for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
                        ExcelFormat::BasicExcelCell * cell = sheet->Cell(row, col);

                        if (cell != nullptr) {
                            std::string value = getval(cell);

                            GetValueCell(foundX, value, col);

                            CheckParams(foundX, foundParams, value, col, params);
                        }

                    }

                    if (willBreak)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        while (foundParams.size() > 0) {
            params->push_back(*foundParams.begin());
            foundParams.erase(foundParams.begin());
        }

        book.Close();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'd like to be able to abstract the methods to open books/sheets into single methods as the process for iterating over each cell.

I've contemplated possible modifying the source of ExcelFormat and The Wrapper class for Xlsx i/o to operate with a unified abstract base.

Would this be the wisest way to go about this?

Is there already a design pattern for this sort of conflict?

Should I implement an adapter class that inherits from Excel Format's class's and then have Xlsxio wrapper and the new adapter classes conform to a new abstract base?

Or does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks.

Edit: Also, side note, I realize this obviously has the long method code smell. I plan to refactor this with the more generalized algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using https://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/ ?
It's slightly less outdated and more portable.

For XLSX I/O I recommend the XLSXIOREAD_SKIP_NONE flag for xlsxioread_process if you need to iterate through all cells including empty ones.

For the rest I think writing a common base class is not obvious like you say, because of the different approaches between the libraries.

My advice would be to make the abstract class as abstract as possible, and that means you shouldn't base that on either one of the libraries, but just their common properties.

Personally I have abandoned .xls support as this is a closed format that Microsoft itself no longer actively uses since Office 2007.